# Wordpress change Language not working

Tags: plugins, code, language, bbpress

My issue is, that I want to change the Language to German (de_CH) and BBPress etc. should change the language too.

I know not all Plugins are available in German. However whatever I do, add them manually, add them with Loco Translate plugin, or trying to switch the language in the General Wordpress settings, it will not change anything.

I very much assume that I have all the permissions set correctly on my server because I did it as the documentation of Wordpress tells me.

Does anyone have a clue what could be the issue? (I can, however, change the Wordpress language itself without a problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bbPress doesn't have a **de_CH** translation available. All available languages for bbPress are listed here with the translation progress:https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/bbpress.

Comment: ok, but when I set my language to de_DE it won't work either.

Comment: huh... i switched to de_DE, deleted the plugin in the backend, and reinstalled. tadaa!! German.
Well i wasted like 4 hours of my life. Thanks.